# Can I use a hardtail for MTB trail riding?

Tags: frames, fork

So, I have a tight budget of 600 USD. Now, I just wanted to say that I live in a big city, but I do want to ride trails more often. My intended use with the bike is to ride trails, and perform techniques like bunny hopping, manual, etc in order to ride streets. But after researching, I found that trail bikes are usually full suspensions - much more expensive than my budget. Can I ride trails with hardtails (120mm forks) and whether I should build my own bike or buy new.

Comment: Building your own bike is expensive (usually moreso than buying a bike with comparable components), and buying new bikes is expensive. Look at the used bike market in your area (and if you know what size you need, going online can be a good option too, but shipping eats a good portion of the budget).

Comment: We don't do specific product recommendations because they're invariably local and become outdated quickly (will the recommendation be useful in even one year, let alone five? Or to someone in the US rather than Estonia?)

Comment: Buy a $100 used bike and ride it for 6-12 months.  That will let you find out what you like and don't like.  Remember, suspension is not needed at all for urban riding, and beginner "trails" can be done rigid.  You might end up with a town bike and a off-road bike, rather than a single compromise.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost... Yes, you can definitely ride trails on a hardtail and it will help you get lots of technical skills that a full suspension bike wouldn't give you, unless you jumped class (enduro) on a trail bike. Plus, it will be way more comfortable riding in the city. Secondly, given your budget, i would suggest you didn't make a custom one. Buy a new one. There are lots of good ones on that budget.

Comment: Alright, thanks for giving me a good answer. Now what I want to ask is that should I get an Avalanche 2014 with a Rockshox XC30, Trail 5 with an XCT fork or a Karokoram Comp 2014? Note that I'm 161cm, and I ride streets and trials

Comment: The avalanche's 26" wheels will let you go more technical. This bike is very easy to learn on. Trail 5 is also a good option, with 27,5" wheels. Although learning the technical stuff wil require more efford, it will give you better rolling in both dirt and tarmac due to the wheel size. Plus, if you master the 27,5" everything is plain sail later on. The Karokoram is out of the question, because it's 29" and that means you already have to have skills to go out for something more than a ride, which i assume you want to pursue. Try both avalanche and trail 5 and get the most suitable for you.

Comment: I'd steer away from 26", its an outdated wheel size, and spare parts are already becoming less easy to get hold of.

Comment: Cannondale Trail then!

Comment: @AndyP, actually, exactly due to outdating of the 26", spare parts hit some insane price reductions. Browse around the German web shops. **Chris** - the best explanation on wheel sizes I have read so far. Ever!

Comment: Using Avalanche for just everything (xc, trail, commuting...). Spare parts costs are really good - much better than for my friends 29"

Answer (score 2):

You can ride anything on anything... have a look for "Martin Ashton Road Bike Party" on Youtube to see what I mean.

The original mountain bikes were fixed frame bikes with wide (1.9") knobbly tyres and an extra chain ring at the front.  Don't get taken in by the "need" for suspension.  You don't need it, that's why your elbows and knees bend.

Having said that - do your homework and find the best you can get for the money, not just the most expensive.  And read the reviews!

Answer (score 1):

I ride a Giant Talon hard tail MTB with 27:5 in tires that cost around 650 offroad all the time here in Montana on the rocky uneven trails of the Bitterroot mountains. I also ride it in town almost every day as my main source of transportation. Hard tail mountain bikes are also great for bikepacking with panniers or a trailer. I use both and the stability of the bike is great as well as gearing and geometry. https://www.adventurecycling.org/adventure-cyclist/online-features/how-to-mountain-bike-tour/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can absolutely use a hardtail for trail riding.  In fact some manufacturers are making hardtails specifically designed for this, with slack head angles and beefy forks.

As an example, here is the [Orange Crush](https://www.orangebikes.co.uk/bikes/crush-rs) (plenty of other choices out there), with a 66deg head angle, 140mm fork and clearance for 2.4" tyres.

For your budget I would look for a good quality second hand bike, as usually hardtails around this price point will have a steeper head angle more suited to XC riding and not so good suspension fork (both in terms of ride quality and stiffness).